# Showing records that are not yet in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a User,student,Course and subject table

The Student table has the user_id I setup a one to one relationship, because a student is a user.

So in my Student regitration I have a create function that gets all the course subjects which that student is currently enrolled and I did it like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $student_id = Student::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
    $course = $student_id->course->id;
    $subjects = Subject::where('course_id', $course)->get();
    return view('student.create', compact('subjects'));
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action'=>'StudentRegistration@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <div class="label-box">
        {!! Form::label('subject_id', $subject->name) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('subject_id[]', $subject->id, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create User', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>      
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then in the store method I manage to update the pivot table (student_subject)

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $data = $request->except('_token');
    $subject_count = count($data['subject_id']);
    for($i=0; $i < $subject_count; $i++){
       $student = Student::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
       $student->subjects()->attach($data['subject_id'][$i]);
    }
```

However, I noticed that even though the student is registered for a particular subject, the same subject still show in the registration index view, which will lead him to do double registrations.

So, How can I view only the subjects of that course where student belongs to, and that are not yet in the pivot table?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please, edit your question and replace the image with the arrays.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I just edited

Comment: But what do you want exactly? Can you show us the desired output please?

Comment: Did you read [array_udiff](http://us.php.net/array_udiff) documentation?

Comment: @WosleyAlarico So what have you tried? And what have you not understood? The link you mentioned is exactly what you need. If the callback passed to array_udiff returns zero for any of the comparisons then the current handled element will not be in the returned array from array_udiff().

Comment: So the result that you want is the subject with the `id:5` ?

Comment: Yes @HamzaAbdaoui. Except that it will have to be inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are working with Laravel Collections, I would suggest using the following method given by the Laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-diffassoc

Hopefully this will help you with your problem.

Comment: Can you provide more details for this?

Comment: I used the provided link and now I am able to get one object only.
  $collection = collect($subjects);
  $diff = $collection->diff($subjects2);
  echo $diff->first();

If I try the all method it does not work.

Comment: It gives this error if I use the all method: "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Before I continue on answering. Are you trying to get the difference on keys active in both of the collection? For example: both Collections have the 'course_id' key, but both do not have the 'pivot' key. If that's not the case, I may have another solution for you.

Comment: For Wosley Alarico, try to not echo your outcome but dump it. You cannot echo an Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Route::get('/studentsubjects', function(){
        $student_id = Student::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
        $course = $student_id->course->id;
        $subjects = json_decode($student_id->subjects);
        $subjects2 = json_decode(Subject::where('course_id', $course)->get());
        $subjectsUserNotRegisterd= array_udiff($subjects , $subjects2, function ($obj1, $obj2) {
            return $obj1->id-$obj2->id;
        });
        echo "<pre>", print_r($subjectsUserNotRegisterd, 1);
    });
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [course_id] => 1
            [lecturer_id] => 1
            [code] => Nss101
            [name] => Network Systems
            [created_at] => 2018-05-31 17:43:08
            [updated_at] => 2018-05-31 17:43:08
        )

)
```

Comment: This gives an empty array

Comment: It should give output like that. I have checked on my server to use your output arrays what you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Route to the following code using laravel docs and it works just perfect:

```
Route::get('/studentsubjects', function(){
    $student_id = Student::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    $course = $student_id->course->id;
    $all_subjects = $student_id->subjects;

    $selected_subjects = Subject::where('course_id', $course)->get();

    $nonregistered_subjects = $selected_subjects->diff($all_subjects);

    foreach ($nonregistered_subjects as $nonregistered) {
        echo $nonregistered->name;
    }
});
```